# Pyplot annotate with image (png or numpy array) instead of text

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to annotate a pyplot figure, but not with text or circles or the other similar objects, but an image instead?

For example read a png from a file and present it below a plotted data in the same graph.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html) demo seems to do what you're looking for.  Below is the the resulting plot:

[image: No description needed here.]

Comment: `read_png` got deprecated in more recent versions of matplotlib, and a more updated version of the tutorial using `imread` is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-demo-annotation-box-py)